# Windows phone 8 emulator. How to use?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, emulation

Hello I currently install Visual Studio 2013 update 2 with windows phone8. When I run the application and open the Projects, then I do not see a list of emulators, and I can not run the emulator. Computer: Intel core 2 duo, 4 gb RAM, 2 gb videocard, windows 8.1 professional

Comment: check you startup project also. if it's not wp8 project? VS won't show you emulators list

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a windows phone 8 project using one of the following templates:

[image]

Then, when executing the application; the emulator will load up. You can even select what type of emulator to run at that specific execution!

[image]

Also, don't quote me on this, I believe that after installing the SDK, you can open the emulator without visual studio from the "All programs" menu in Windows 7 or looking for it with "Windows + Q" in windows 8.

If you get lost, take a look at this [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402526%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: My problem is that the list of emulators I only device

Comment: I think you need to install the SDK (comes with VS 2013) and the emulators (don't come with VS by default). http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

Comment: Thank you. It turned out that I just do not support processor virtualization for this emulator